# Asyncsocket VS NSstream

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, sockets

I have to create an sample code that connect to a socket server, and then be able to send multiple NSString through the socket.

In the begging i start using NSStream objects, but i had a problem to reuse the socket (maybe i'll post another question if the nsstream solution is the best), and when i google socket for iPhone programming, i've found the [cocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) project on google code.

So what's the best???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cocoaAsyncSocket is an excellent toolkit for talking to a remote socket. It is built on top of CFSocket, and is going to handle most of the common cases for you. In general, it's my recommended toolkit for this kind of problem.